# Sending the Sproc results to an Email in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to send an email of the Sproc results. I have tried doing this:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
    @recipients = 'Testemail@XYZ.com',
    @query = 'EXEC test_email' ,
    @subject = 'Sample Data',
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 1 ;
```

It gives me the following error:

> Msg 15281, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_send_dbmail, Line 0
>      SQL Server blocked access to procedure 'dbo.sp_send_dbmail' of component 'Database Mail XPs' because this component is turned off as part of the security configuration for this server. A system administrator can enable the use of 'Database Mail XPs' by using sp_configure. For more information about enabling 'Database Mail XPs', see "Surface Area Configuration" in SQL Server Books Online.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: I think the error message is pretty helpful here actually. Have you tried checking with your DBA's to enable the required SQL Server components to send the emails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No other way of using DBMail Im afraid. Database Mail needs to be enabled with:
EXEC sp_configure 'Database Mail XPs', 1
But additionally, Database Mail needs to be configured with an appropriate Profile and account.

One work around I have used for servers where the policy is not to enable mail is to have the stored procedure call a SSIS package that runs the query and sends the email. This bypasses Database Mail entirely and the SSIS package makes its own connection to the SMTP server.

The way I normally set this up is to run sp_startjob to call a Server Agent job, which then runs the SSIS package.